# Unity SceneManager.LoadScene quits application

Tags: unity-game-engine, load, scene

I have two different scenes one is named 'main' and the other 'game' both are added Scenes In Load. When I use              `SceneManager.LoadScene("game");`
works with no problem but when I tried to return to main scene with that code

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape)) {
SceneManager.LoadScene("main");
}
```

strangely the game quits. Thanks.

Comment: Does the game quit with an error or exception?

Comment: Have you got any code in the `main` scene which could cause your game to quit?

Comment: No exception and no error, I am testing on an android device, by the way. And it works in unity with out error.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the interruption. Somewhere on an other script I found that code.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape)) {
        Application.Quit (); 
    }
```

That's my bad, I know...